# how to use async recoil-sync and nextjs? page won't load

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, recoiljs

been stuck on this issue awhile:

When using the RecoilSync component with an async read prop, the nextJs server gets stuck and the page won't load. no error is thrown.

Here is a super simple reproduction:
https://github.com/hainessss/recoil-sync-next

This also happens with next 12.

Any ideas what needs to be done to get this working? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the `default` value.

```js
export const myListState = atom<readonly string[]>({
  key: 'myList',
  default: [],
  effects: [
    syncEffect({
      itemKey: 'myList',
      storeKey: 'my-db',
      refine: array(string())
    })
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! but, If you set the default the server gets unblocked but then the syncEffect doesn't work @user16967562